# How to build sioClient_tls.lib?

Tags: c++

I am trying to integrate sioClient_tls.lib in my project but getting the following the following errors:

```
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_socket.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_system_error_allocate_message referenced in function "public: __cdecl std::_System_error_m
essage::_System_error_message(unsigned long)" (??0_System_error_message@std@@QEAA@K@Z) [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\infurniaVR.vcx
proj]
```

```
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_client.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_system_error_allocate_message [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurnia
VR\infurniaVR_Vk\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_client_impl.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_system_error_allocate_message [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\inf
urniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_socket.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_system_error_deallocate_message referenced in function "public: __cdecl std::_System_error
_message::~_System_error_message(void)" (??1_System_error_message@std@@QEAA@XZ) [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_client.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_system_error_deallocate_message [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurn
iaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_client_impl.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_system_error_deallocate_message [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\i
nfurniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_socket.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4 [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\
infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_client.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4 [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\
infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_packet.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4 [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\
infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_client_impl.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4 [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaV
R_Vk\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_socket.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4 [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_V
k\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_client.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4 [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_V
k\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_packet.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4 [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_V
k\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
sioclient_tls.lib(sio_client_impl.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4 [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurni
aVR_Vk\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\InfurniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\Release\infurniaVR.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals [C:\Users\palas\Palash\work\vr\In
furniaVR\build\src\infurniaVR\infurniaVR_Vk\infurniaVR.vcxproj]
```

How to resolve these errors?

Comment: Usually when I get an error like this I first do a websearch of the function name, for example `std_system_error_deallocate_message` to see what library contains it. If I already am or the results don't make any sense, I doublecheck the version of the library I'm importing to make sure it was compiled for my version of the compiler. Nothing more annoying than finding I've been given a MSVS 2012 library that I've been trying to use with MSVS 2015.

Comment: Please show a [mre]